# Movement of entire image on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am not able to move the image on screen in pygame.

I have tried to move the image but the entire image is not moving but image just expands with KEYDOWN.

```
import sys
import pygame


def run_game():
    """An attempt to develop a simple game."""
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket")
    rocket_ship = pygame.image.load("images/alien_ship.bmp")
    rec = rocket_ship.get_rect()
    screen_rec = screen.get_rect()
    rec.centerx = screen_rec.centerx
    rec.bottom = screen_rec.bottom


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    rec.centerx += 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    rec.centerx -= 5
        screen.blit(rocket_ship, rec)
        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame how to fix 'trailing pixels'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487538/pygame-how-to-fix-trailing-pixels)

Answer (score 1):

When the question says the "image is expanding" - I believe this is just a visual artefact of the previous image not being erased.

If the line:

```
screen.fill( 0,0,0 )  # paint the background black
```

is added at the beginning of the loop:

```
while True:
    screen.fill( 0,0,0 )  # paint the background black
    for event in pygame.event.get():
```

This remove the previously-painted alien from the screen.

A better way to handle this sort of thing is to use [pyGame's built in sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  This might seem like extra work right now, but will save you a lot of hassle in the future, as a lot of the "chores" involved with moving things around (and detecting collisions, etc.) are already handled by pygame's sprite code.